# OpenLayers 3: Center ScaleLine in target DIV

Tags: openlayers, scale-bar

I am displaying a scale in a DIV:

[image]

I would like to display the scale in the center of that DIV.

There does not seem to be an option for that so I am trying to use CSS.

The following, however, does not work (using margin with a specific amout of pixels does work):

```
.ol-scale-line {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

How would I go about centering that scalebar?

Answer (score 2):

```
.ol-scale-line {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0)
}
```

Based on https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#vertical3

Transform for Internet Explorer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj127312(v=vs.85).aspx